# Taking time duration in json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I want to store duration of all the **N PROCESSES **in json objects in the format of hh:mm:ss . But the problem is that all the formats are for displaying the current time .

for example if i get 30 min as the duration of the n processes working duration, then it should store 00:30:00. How to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a way to represent structured data with pure text, providing a common syntaxe that can be used by multiple applications. In this way it is much like XML. This means that javascript objects cant be saved inside a JSON, only their serialization, so what you need to save to represent duration is a string in the form HH:MM:SS, that you can later interpret in whatever application will use this data.

Edited with provided data format:

```
{ 
    "process" :"process-name 2", 
    "stage" : "stage name 2", 
    "duration": "02:00:00",
    "activities": [ 
        { 
            "activity_name": "waiting", 
            "start": "2012-10-22T06:45+05:30", 
            "end": "2012-10-25T08:45+05:30", 
            "color": "#CDC9C9"
        } 
    ]
}
```

Use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your json if you are not sure if it is valid

Comment: {
 "process" :"process-name 2",
 "stage" : "stage name 2",
        "duration": 
 "activities": [
  {
  "activity_name": "waiting",
  "start": new Date('2012-10-22T06:45+05:30'),
  "end": new Date('2012-10-25T08:45+05:30'),
  "color": "#CDC9C9",
  }
 ]
 

This is my code .  the place where it says duration , I want to store the duration time as I have mentioned above . My only worry is if I store it in the format 00:00:00 , my java script will read it as time instead of duration.

Comment: @adithya JSON doesn't support date objects, so how the format is interpreted is completely up to you.

Comment: @adithya Save the date string your using to create the Date object instead of the date object. JSON is pure text that represents structured information, much like XML, so you cant save javascript objects.

Comment: so is there a way where in pure javascript where i can save in the duration format ??

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "save", and what a duration format is... You can easily save the number of seconds, or save hours minutes and seconds in separate attributes, or save a h:m:s string, or even a serialized date object. In the end you will always have to convert the saved date into a javascript date object.